# programmatically embedding segmented control inside navigation bar

Tags: swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol, programmatically-created

I am trying to insert a segmented control inside a navigation bar programmatically and am having some trouble loading the segmented controller in the nav bar. I am sure this very simple, but see code below. Thanks in advance!

```
var segmentedController: UISegmentedControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.titleView = segmentedController
    let items = ["Label A", "Label B"]
    segmentedController = UISegmentedControl(items: items)

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Sign Out", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleSignOut))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.black

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add the `segmentedController` to the navigation bar after initializing it!

```
var segmentedController: UISegmentedControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let items = ["Label A", "Label B"]
    segmentedController = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
    navigationItem.titleView = segmentedController

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Sign Out", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleSignOut))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.black
}
```